# Should I place a redirect on a url that is rewritten in htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, seo

For example

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^tour/?$    tour-info.php    [NC,L]
```

www.site.com/tour/ will look inside www.site.com/tour-info.php

My question is: Is it bad SEO practice to leave www.site.com/tour-info.php as an addressable url or should a redirect be placed on it?

**UPDATE**

If you have the htaccess code below...How can you make it more efficient using regex?
Also, in terms of SEO should accessible pages such as "tours/a.php" redirect back to "tours/a/"  or to the homepage?

I am in the process of updating my website's url structure. The urls I am rewriting have not been crawled yet.

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -Indexes
RewriteRule ^tours/?$ tours.php
RewriteRule ^tours/a/?$ tours/a.php
RewriteRule ^tours/b/?$ tours/b.php
RewriteRule ^tours/c/?$ tours/c.php
RewriteRule ^tours/d/?$ tours/d.php
RewriteRule ^tours/e/?$ tours/e.php
RewriteRule ^tours/f/?$ tours/f.php
RewriteRule ^tours/g/?$ tours/g.php
```

Comment: Yes better to avoid duplicate content so redirect back to `/tour` from `.php`

Comment: Set a redirect and don't forget to add a canonical link to site.com/tour in the markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a 301 redirect so anything indexing the old URL will get pointed to the new one:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \+ /tour-info\.php(\?|\ |$)
RewriteRule ^ /tour/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: What is the difference between 

    RewriteRule ^/tour-info.php www.site.com/tour/ [R=301]

and

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \+ /tour-info\.php(\?|\ |$)
    RewriteRule ^ /tour/ [L,R=301]

Comment: @Obi-Wan The regex of the `RewriteRule` checks against the current URI, which could be what the browser requested, what was previously rewritten by another rewrite rule, what was an internal redirect, etc. The `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable is **only ever** what the browser requested.

Comment: When you have a moment I would appreciate your input on my updated original question. Thank you very much.